# Assembly for 64bit platform

Tags: assembly

I'm a beginner programmer and I want to start with the assembly language but all I find to learn is Assembly for X86 Processors family ... is it familiar to the new modern processors ?

Comment: You really should start with something easier like mips. x86 and x86-64 are about as complicated as it gets.

Comment: You actually don't want to start with Assembly language.  Work from a higher level down.

Comment: I have a good idea about C++ but I never like it ... I want to be more closer to the Hardware ...... if I learn assembly for X86 processors ( which si the only available ) will it fit me to work on the latest processors ?

Comment: I think this is a mistake, learning assembly is almost impossible if you are not familiar with concepts such as pointers which are much more understandable in higher level languages. If you want to stay close to the machine master  C instead.

Comment: The concept of a "pointer" in C or similar languages becomes a "memory location which holds an address" in assembler which is much more clear IMHO. I did know assembler before I started with C (due to the lack of C compilers in that time) and when I encountered pointers for the first time I immediately recognized them. Now watch the kids today who start with Java or Python (fine languages of course) and see their heads explode when they hear about pointers the first time.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, its actually better to start of with x86 32bit assembly, mainly cuse the resources are just so much better. you will still be learning the same basics for x64, so you won't loose out (put very simply, x86-64 is merely an extension the the x86 instruction set and architecture).

Any x86-64 processor would also be able to run the 32bit assembly (at least at operating system level, using things like WOW64), so you don't need to change your environment either.

Moving up to x86-64 just a fwe major things to be aware of:

- More registers
- Major changes in calling conventions (and ABI, see System V and the AMD64 ABI's for x64)
- Changes in how system calls are made
- More address space
- RIP addressing
- Loss of segement registers apart from `GS` & `FS`
- REX.W prefixing for forced 64bit addressing

There are quick a few other changes, but these can be gotten from the Intel or AMD system architecture manuals, which are a great resource for both 32 & 64 bit development.

When working with 'modern processors', most desktop and notebook processors are x86 based, with all of them being 64bit & 32bit compatible, you won't need to really worry about if the assembly you learn will work on modern processors, because it will. The only time those concerns could be raised is if you are working with extensions like SSE and AXV, which may include vendor specific instructions or you need to work with non-x86 family processors (like ARM or SPARC).

Answer (score 2):

This is rather subjective.  There's nothing really wrong with the x86 architecture.  It has been wildly successful and you'll have no trouble finding assemblers, debuggers, emulators and books for it.  You do have to be a wee bit selective about what particular version you pick, an x86 core can run 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit code.  Testament to its longevity.  You write very different assembly code for each.  It is easy to get stuck into 16-bit mode, popular this year in India, but otherwise quite irrelevant since 16-bit operating systems are a museum artifact.

But it ultimately doesn't matter.  When you master one particular kind of assembly then you'll know how to tackle all the other ones.  It will take you several months to get up to speed on the first one.  The next one takes a couple of weeks.

The only practical lesson here is that it *is* a bit of a waste of your time.  Nobody actually writes machine code anymore.  Writing fast code for a modern core is incredibly difficult because the core doesn't actually execute the assembly code directly.  It has a compiler built in hardware that converts the machine code to micro-op instructions for the native execution engine built in the chip.  Which has *way* more registers than x86 supports, has multiple functional units that allows executing instructions in parallel and has caches to reduce the delays of accessing memory.

It takes a machine to generate the code that optimizes the arcane rules of the nderlying hardware.  And software, embedded in the code generation stage of a C compiler.

Comment: I agree that it may be a waste of your time to learn to **write** assembly. That said, being able to **read** assembly is a valuable skill (for perf analysis, debugging, working with binaries, etc.). And IMHO nearly every programmer would benefit from at least a basic understanding of assembly-level concepts like registers, stack, calling conventions, etc.

Comment: @Igor - Agreed.  The better highlight in my answer is 'When you master one particular kind of assembly'.

Comment: IMHO writing something is always easier than reading, especially when some time has passed in between :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage you from learning x86 assembly as your first assembly it is a very ugly instruction set, for many reasons.

I have a number of instruction set simulators http://github.com/dwelch67.

thumbulator, thumb is a subset of the ARM instruction set which is at this time the most portable arm instruction set (works on almost all the ARM cores).  Orthogonal, straightforward, etc not a bad first instruction set.

msp430sim I think I called it is an msp430 simulator, a nice and simple instruction set, very clean, very straightforward.  a good first instruction set.

the avr simulator I have avriss is not all that well tested so stay away for a while. not a bad instruction set, msp430 is probably best first then avr later.

I have my own instruction set lsasim which was made for learning assembler.  and has a tutorial you can try.

If you really really feel you must learn x86 first I strongly recommend going back to the roots of intel and start with the 8088/8086.  I have forked the pcemu emulator and ripped out the bios calls so that it is just an instruction set simulator, the reason for learning asm right, to learn the instructions, if you want to learn bios calls you should learn the assembly language first, bios calls later.

most recently I added a fork of the amber arm2 processor from opencores.  I made it run in verilator, and all that means to you is that you can run it without needing any hardware or any expensive simulators, it works with all free tools.  The arm2 is the precedessor to the ARM family of processors widely used today.  by learning the arm2 instruction set if you take this path will build a solid foundation for the current arm family in addition to it not being a bad instruction set, much better than x86, but has many instructions and many ways to use each instruction so can be unwieldy at first.

The amber/arm and thumbulator work with gcc cross compilers which are easy to come by, codesourcery lite for example.  msp430 and avr you can find gcc derivatives or build your own if you follow their instructions.

If you have no programming skills at all I recommend you start with the learning python the hard way tutorial. it is not hard.  the hard part is just do what he tells you to do, dont fight it, just type it in and run it, then find out what it did.  Once you have some basic programming skills spend a half an hour or so on my lsasim tutorial, get your feet wet with some basics.  Then go to one of the others msp430 or thumb and then arm then x86.  If you try a few, sane, instruction sets first, the x86 will be somewhat trivial, if you try x86 first it will be painful and you will have to re-learn some basics to move to other instruction sets.  Just because you have x86 hardware does not mean you should try to use that for learning.  That is also a hard way to start.  using a simulator you can if you want view what is going on.  Esp with the amber arm2 core.  Once you know assembly though each programming language, assembly or other, is just a matter of syntax...